# Symfony2 host url translation

Tags: php, symfony, translation, yaml, host

I am new with Symfony2 (using 2.7, because It's an existing project). I have to create translated urls for a website with the locale in the hostname of the url.

For being more clear, I will take thoses examples:

**en.mywebsite.com/hello** for US/English version
or
**fr.mywebsite.com/bonjour** for French version

I have my routing.yml file, but of course, it doesn't work.

```
helloRoute:
   host: "{locale}.mywebsite.com"
   path: I don't know the correct input, it can be "/hello" or "/bonjour"
   defaults: {_controller: MyWebSiteBundle:Front:viewHello}
   requirements:
      locale: fr|en
```

There is my Nginx configuration:

```
server {
   listen                               80;
   server_name                          ~^(?<region>\.|en|fr)\.\mywebsite.com;
    root                                /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/web/web;

    rewrite                             ^/app_dev\.php/?(.*)$ /$1 permanent;

    location / {
        index                           app_dev.php;
        try_files                       $uri @rewriteapp;
    }
    ...
}
```

No problem for this Nginx configuration, That works.

I had checked a lot of documentation, but I can't do this. The Symfony documentation is not very detailed about that.

I need to have urls translated which depends on hostname locale. Perhaps it's not possible with Symfony.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would create two routes:

for english

```
helloRoute:
   host: "{_locale}.mywebsite.com"
   path: "/hello"
   defaults: {_controller: MyWebSiteBundle:Front:viewHello}
   requirements:
      locale: en
```

for french

```
bonjourRoute:
   host: "{_locale}.mywebsite.com"
   path: "/bonjour"
   defaults: {_controller: MyWebSiteBundle:Front:viewHello}
   requirements:
      locale: fr
```

*Take note that you for got the leading underscore in the locale variable.

You can send both routes to the same controller and present conditionally according to the locale.

Comment: Ok thats works, the page is displaying. But there is another problem more complex I think.

based of this url : en.mywebsite.com/hello
if I modify it in the browser and replace "hello" by "bonjour", I want the host also change in fr.mywebsite.com/bonjour

How I can do it ?

Comment: It will only change if your locale changes. To test you will have to change the lacale setting in the browser

Comment: Ok I understand, my locale is not changing, but the url has changed. I want specify to the router that's the locale in the host is also depending of the url set. (/bonjour or /hello), the comportement is not normal.

Comment: In my opinion it would be a mess to have to duplicate all the translated routes (imagine if at one point you have 3 or 4 languages..), don't you think ?

Answer (score 1):

More generally, to be able to easily handle internationalization in URL with Symfony 2, you could use [BeSimple/BeSimpleI18nRoutingBundle](https://github.com/BeSimple/BeSimpleI18nRoutingBundle).

Then, as shown in the example, you could do something like that :

```
helloRoute:
   host: "{locale}.mywebsite.com"
   locales:  { en: "/hello", fr: "/bonjour" }
   defaults: {_controller: MyWebSiteBundle:Front:viewHello}
   requirements:
      locale: fr|en
```

Comment: I am searching about this Bundle. After a try I had a error message in the page render:
"No route found for "GET /bonjour" with the url www.mywebsite.com/bonjour

Comment: Aren't you supposed to use only `en.mywebsite.com` and `fr.mywebsite.com` as specified in your `requirements:` ? You can handle a redirection from `www` to the correct prefix manually though, with a [Listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html) for example.

Comment: sorry my bad, I wanna tape fr instead of www. So it still doesn't work, same error message.

Comment: Did you include the `be_simple_i18n` routings ? Although I just noticed this bundle hasn't been updated for a year, so there might be some issues..

Comment: Yep I include the be_simple_i18n file nammed i18n.yml in my routing.yml file.

Comment: Maybe you could use the command `app/console router:debug` to dump all the routes and find out what's wrong.